# Submit a form only once in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to make the user submit a form only once. I have a /dashboard page which is shown after submitting the /petform. But, I want the user to submit the form only once after logging in and other times it should redirect to the /dashboard directly (or show a message that "form already submitted").

models.py

```
class PetFormData(models.Model):
    abstract = True
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount_spent = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=AMOUNT_CHOICES)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    services_required = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=SERVICE_CHOICES)
    auth_user_email = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    form_submitted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def showformdata(request):
    form = PetForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not PetFormData.form_submitted and user == PetFormData.auth_user_email:
            PetFormData.form_submitted = True
            print(PetFormData.form_submitted)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = request.user
                nm = form.cleaned_data['name']
                age = form.cleaned_data['age']
                breed = form.cleaned_data['breed']
                am_sp = form.cleaned_data['amount_spent']
                pin = form.cleaned_data['pincode']
                ser_req = ','.join(form.cleaned_data['services_required'])
                model_pet_form = PetFormData(name=nm, age=age, breed=breed, amount_spent=am_sp, pincode=pin,
                                             services_required=ser_req, auth_user_email=user)
                model_pet_form.save()
                print(session_data)
                return redirect('/dashboard')
        else:
            print(PetFormData.form_submitted)
            return HttpResponse('Form already submitted', content_type="text/plain")
    else:
        form = PetForm()
    return render(request, 'petform.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Why do you have a boolean field `form_submitted` (that is by default `False`)?

Comment: If you see the models.py file, I am checking if 'form_submitted' is false, if not I am saving the form fields to the database. If not, the message is shown saying "form already submitted". My idea to do this was to make the user submit the form ONLY once. But is is not working I guess

Comment: use HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)

Answer (score 0):

Successfully submitting the form once presumably stores something in the database. A subsequent visit to that page can interrogate the database, discover it has already been done, and display the appropriate next page.

Something like this (I don't fully understand your problem)

```
if PetFormData.objects.filter( auth_user_email = request.user).exists() :
    return redirect('/dashboard')

# OK, user hasn't submitted yet.
```

Comment: Thank you so much @nigel222! This worked for me. Appreciate your quick response